# Pip install does not work, matplotlib seems to be broken, pyenv and fresh new install doesn't work

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, pip, pyenv

So I wanted to import matplotlib to my virtual python version of 3.10.0 (and other versions). I install it as usual:

`pip install matplotlib`

Everything seems to work, no errors show up with pip. But when I try to run this code snippet in vs code (to see if mpl works):

`import matplotlib`

`print(matplotlib.__version__)`

It outputs this:

```
File "/Users/XYZ/Desktop//pienv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/Users/XYZ/Desktop//matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package
```

But when I do the same in the terminal it outputs the correct version.
It doesn't matter if I have python installed with dmg file or with pyenv, result is the same.

I tried to format operating system to ensure there is no os trash that might be getting in a way. Then I just installed python with pyenv.

I'm using osx 12.0.1

My vscode setup is straightforward, just python extension and python interpreter set to what pyenv has as a local python.

Is there that can be done, or that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

It's just a stupid thing.

Don't name your projects with the names of your libraries when they're in the same directory.